# Result set from two tables looping multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables from which I'm pulling data

Table 1 : assignment_status

```
primary_key   
test_group_id | s_id | date_taken | status
q1            | 123  | 2012-08-13 | completed
```

Table 2: question_bank

```
 foreign key    unique key |
 group_id     | q_id       | question
 q1           | 1          | What is your name?
 q1           | 2          | Where were you born?
```

Table 3: assignment_answers

```
foreign key  
g_id         | q_id | s_id  | s_answer
q1           | 1    |  123  | Mark Johnson
q1           | 2    |  123  | Florida
```

Now I'm attempting to display the answer for it's corresponding question. The problem I'm facing is that the result set returned is looping multiple times.

For example, if `question_bank` and `assignment_answers` have 2 records each the result set has 4 records; if both have 4 records each the result set has 16 records. So the number is getting squared. This makes me sure that I'm pulling it in a wrong manner. Below is my query that I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    assignment_status s, 
    question_bank b, 
    assignment_answers a
WHERE 
    s.test_group_id = b.group_id = a.g_id = 'q1'
```

I also tried

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    question_bank b, 
    assignment_answers a
WHERE 
    b.group_id = a.g_id
    AND b.group_id = 'q1'
    AND a.g_id = 'q1'
```

Both queries result in same multiple rows being repeated.

Any suggestions, ideas, thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact 'question' that you are trying to answer through your query ? ( is it : who answered this question ? ) i think you might also want to use Distinct

Comment: The answer for the question the student selected. For ex: What is your name? - Student answered 'Mark'. Where do you live? - Student answered 'Florida'. So i want to display this on page

Comment: Ha i see so u need to add the condition b.q_id = a_q.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a condition for question_bank b,  assignment_answers a

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    assignment_status s, 
    question_bank b, 
    assignment_answers a
WHERE 
    s.test_group_id = b.group_id = a.g_id = 'q1' AND b.q_id = a_q.id
```

Comment: Oh yes..that was spot on. Wonder how I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have your questions/answers identified by 2 columns, so you should use them when you join tables. Something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT as.s_id, as.date_taken, as.status,
       qb.group_id, qb.q_id, qb.question,
       aa.s_answer
  FROM assignment_status as
  JOIN question_bank qb ON as.test_group_id = qb.group_id
  JOIN assignment_answers aa ON aa.g_id = qb.group_id AND aa.q_id = qb.q_id
 WHERE as.test_group_id = 'q1';
```

Note: you have columns in your tables named differently, like `test_group_id <--> group_id <--> g_id`. This is considered a bad style, 'cos when your schema will grow to hundreds of tables, it will be difficult to write queries. So it is a good habbit to use a common naming pattern and name columns in different tables similarily.